# On the elliptic curve $x^4+y^4 =193z^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

Given the simultaneous Diophantine equations,

$$u^2+v^2=w^2\tag{1}$$

$$x^4+y^4 = (u^6+v^6)t^2\tag{2}$$

the only solutions seem to be for the first *Pythagorean triple* $u,v,w = 3,4,5$ which yield the elliptic curve,

$$x^4+y^4 = 193z^2$$

with initial solution $x,y = 18,31$. Or alternatively,

$$s^4+1 = 193t^2$$

which has initial rational point $s = 18/31$ (and an infinite more) and is birationally *equivalent* to an elliptic curve in Weierstrass form.

*Question*: Are there other **co-prime** $u,v$, such that (2) is solvable?  (I did a quick search using Mathematica and didn't find any, though my search radius for $x,y$ could just have been too small.)

Comment: $x^4+y^4=193z^2$ is not an elliptic curve.

Comment: i have seen this question before on Math.SE

Comment: @Alvaro: It is not in the usual form, but you can easily convert it to one.

Comment: Then convert it to one: a quartic equation is not an elliptic curve.

Comment: @exploringnet: yes, i deleted that question as I forgot the requirement that $u,v,w$ be a Pythagorean triple (eq.1). Without it, eq. 2 has a lot of solutions. When I couldn't find others with eq.1 as a constraint, I decided to restore the question.

Comment: The problem is not the degree, for instance, see Cassels, Lectures on elliptic curves, chapter 8.

Comment: @Myself...? Whose comment are you addressing? And I've Cassels's book in front of me, open at chapter 8,  but I'm not sure what I'm looking for...

Comment: @DonAntonio Your comment :-) Cassels explains how to convert curves to standard form. For instance, y^2 = a quartic in x (with rational point) is an elliptic curve.

Comment: @Myself , could you please tell me the page(s) you're looking at?

Comment: Page 35. (Note that x^4+y^4 = z^2 is non-homogeneous with 3 variables in it.)

Comment: I think I found it: it is case (iii) in a very horrible try to prove a theorem which he calls "fact" for "the non-cognoscenti" (particular cases), and his try looks to me the same as telling that putting $\,t^2:=x\,$ makes the quartic $\,y=x^4=t^2\,$ into a parabola...well, yes it does. :)

Comment: @myself: Thank you. I knew a bi-rational transformation could transform that quartic into the standard form, hence it was just an elliptic curve in disguise.

Comment: The point is that if it is a curve of genus 1 (with base point) and if you can bring it into its canonical form y^2 = x^3 + ax + b with a birational transformation then you can use standard methods to find points on it. I claim no further expertise, but this curve looks more like a surface to me.

Comment: Have you tried reducing to a non-symmetrical sum-of-squares? By (1) we have
$$
w^6 = (u^2+v^2)^3 = u^6+v^6 + 3u^2v^2(u^2+v^2),
$$
so (2) is
\begin{align}
  x^4+y^4 &= \bigl(w^6-3u^2v^2(u^2+v^2)\bigr)t^2,
\end{align}
and hence we get
\begin{align}
  (x^2)^2 + (y^2)^2 + 3(u^2vt)^2 + 3(uv^2t)^2 &= (w^3t)^2,
\end{align}
an equation of the form $A^2+B^2+3C^2+3D^2=E^2$. Do you have a parameterization for that? Since you already have the parameterization $(u,v,w)=(m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2)$, you might be able to either find a contradiction or discover a new solution.